# Android Cursor loader initialize slow

Tags: android, android-listview

I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/525313/Using-Cursor-Loader-in-Android) to implement CursorLoader for listview in fragment. Everything is fine when scrolling in listview (even fast scroll, it very smooth), except the first time I switch to this fragment, cursor loader load slow a bit. Does any one know how to speed it up? here is my try:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

   String[] projection = { DatabaseHandler.UserTable.id, DatabaseHandler.UserTable.name };

   cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, DatabaseAccessUtility.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
   return cursorLoader;

}

 public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader,Cursor cursor) {
   if(mAdapter!=null && cursor!=null)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

 public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
if(mAdapter!=null)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Comment: do you load Views by yourself (getView method) ?

Comment: Yes, I load view by myself in adapter. Is there any problem?

Comment: could be, add some Log.d with timestamps and see how long it takes

Comment: In one page without scrolling listview, it takes total about 200ms - 300ms

Comment: 200/300 for *one* View or for the whole ListView?

Comment: No, for rows display in on page screen (without scroll). I think my adapter doesn't have any problem, because when I scroll, it very fast and smoothly.

Comment: ok so it seems that you should use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#startMethodTracing() and see where the bottleneck is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40331/discussion-between-r4j-and-pskink)